# Failed to load Json File in Kaggle Kernel using load_dataset(), but works in Google Colab and Local System

Tags: json, kaggle, huggingface-datasets

I am trying to load a json file using the load_dataset method in the Huggingface Datasets library in the Kaggle Kernel. This is the code:

```
data=load_dataset("json",data_files="/kaggle/input/dataset/gold_summaries_test.json")
```

I get the following error **only** when I am working in the **Kaggle Kernel**.

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

Below is a preview of the json file I am trying to load.

[gold_summaries_test.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ve6XH.png)

This error does not occur when loading the file in Google Colab, or on a python console in my local system.

Comment: Hi @Jishnu. Would you mind to show me how you have resolved it? Because I'm facing the same problem now as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

load_dataset on kaggle need json with struct like:

```
{
 "data" : [{
   "a": "one",
   "b": "two"
},
{
   "a": "three",
   "b": "four"
}]
}
```

and use load_dataset as below:

```
dataset = load_dataset("json", data_files=file_path, field="data")
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem and loaded to Dataset successfully by using from_dict. I tried load_dataset but failed due to the same error.

```
import json
json_file_path = '/kaggle/input/pii-detection-removal-from-educational-data/train.json'
with open(json_file_path, 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
from datasets import Dataset
dataset = Dataset.from_dict({"data": data})
```